# What is the difference between "bracelet" and "strap" when talking about watches?

Tags: meaning

I talked to my friend about his watch. I used the word "strap" to refer to his watch's strap while he used the word "bracelet."

Is there any difference between these words? Can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 2):

*Straps* are usually made of leather or a synthetic fiber material. *Bracelets* are usually made of metal. Often the word *band* will be used to represent either, though.

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider these as items without the watch to understand the meaning.

- A *strap* is typically a strip of material for attaching things, and often has a buckle
- A *bracelet* is an item of adornment, usually closed around the wrist and often made of links
- A *bangle* is typically a rigid bracelet, so for some a *bracelet* by contrast suggests flexibility

Now you attach a watchface and you have the fully meaning.  Since the meanings can overlap some cases can fall into more than one category.  So for example this [*semi-bangle watch*](http://www.hsamuel.co.uk/webstore/d/5381827/sekonda+ladies%27+semi-bangle+stone-set+watch/) means a watch set on a rigid semi-circle, but with flexible links at the back, with the whole support described as the strap.

Comment: Now you attach a watchface and you have the fully meaning. Since the meanings can overlap some cases can fall into more than one category. So for example a semi-bangle watch means a watch set on a rigid semi-circle, but with flexible links at the back, with the whole support described as the strap.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my interpretation of these two terms is slightly different to the two answers already given.

A *strap* is usually something that is or can be *fastened* by means of a clip or buckle.

A *bracelet* generally isn't fastened (although in some instances it can be) and consists of a circular shape or in terms of a watch probably expandable. Eg. *expandable bracelet*.

Comment: Two Google image searches (one for "watch bracelet" and the other for "watch strap") would appear to back you up on this. Just saying.

Comment: @J.R. Curious isn't it that the two answers that aren't necessarily correct by definition have upvotes, yet mine that is probably more definitively correct, has none :)